# Django template. API request causes page to navigate to query url

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a django template that includes a button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getRota()">Make Rota</button>
```

The getRota() function is defined below, in a script:

```
<script>
    function getRota() {
        var startDate = $("input[name='rota_start']").val();
        var endDate = $("input[name='rota_end']").val();
        fetch(`{{ rota_url }}start=${startDate}&end=${endDate}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                    $("#rota_form").append(`<a href=${data.url} target="_blank">Text Rota</a>`);
                });
    }

</script>
```

The weird bit, is that pressing the button causes the page to make the API request, append the link (all good so far), and then shortly afterwards, navigate to the URL of the original page (not the api), with the `start=${startDate}&end=${endDate}` (from the api url) appended to it...

I really don't even know where to start with this one...

Comment: The button has `type="submit"` and you're not calling `preventDefault`, so the form it's a part of is getting submitted. This probably explains what you're seeing, although you don't share the form html - I'm guessing it submits via GET and has `start` and `end` fields...

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, it does. So just get rid of the type=submit?

Comment: Yes, that would work

Comment: @RobinZigmond Great, thank you. If you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button has `type="submit"` and you're not calling `preventDefault`, so the form it's a part of is getting submitted. This probably explains what you're seeing, although you don't share the form html - I'm guessing it submits via GET and has `start` and `end` fields.

Since it appears you don't need the form to directly submit to the server (as you're doing it via ajax), there are at least 3 very simple fixes:

- put `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` (`submit` is the default so you can't just leave it out)
- remove the form entirely, and just have inputs and a button
- call `preventDefault` on the event in your Javascript